# Spring batch not reading all records when partitioner is configured

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to configure the spring batch with partitioning. However, I have seen that not all the records are read from the database. I have 10254 records (test records) in my table and I want to split them into multiple steps so that they can be processed parallelly. With the below configuration, if I set the gridSize to 1, it will only read 5150 records, but if provide 10 for the gridSize it will work as expected.

```
    @Bean
    public RepositoryItemReader<RecurringEarning> reader() {
        RepositoryItemReader<RecurringEarning> reader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
        reader.setRepository(recurringEarningRepository);
        reader.setName("recurringEarningRepository");
        reader.setMethodName("findRunnableRecurringEarnings");
        reader.setArguments(List.of(LocalDate.now()));
        reader.setPageSize(chunkSize);
        reader.setSort(Map.of("id", Sort.Direction.ASC));
        return reader;
    }
```

and below is my partitioner

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RecurringEarningPartitioner implements Partitioner {
    private final RecurringEarningRepository recurringEarningRepository;

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        int min = 1;
        int max = recurringEarningRepository.countValidRecords(LocalDate.now());
        log.info("Matched record count = {}", max);

        Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<>();

        int recordsPerPartition = max / gridSize;
        int remainingRecords = max % gridSize;

        int start = min;
        int end = min + recordsPerPartition - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
            ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();
            result.put("partition" + i, value);

            if (i < remainingRecords) {
                end++;
            }

            value.putInt("minValue", start);
            value.putInt("maxValue", end);

            start = end + 1;
            end += recordsPerPartition;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

and below is my job and steps configuration

```
    @Bean
    public Job recurringEarningJob(RecurringEarningCompletionListener listener, Step masterStep) {
        return new JobBuilder("recurringEarningJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .start(masterStep)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step masterStep(RecurringEarningPartitioner partitioner, Step slaveStep) {
        return new StepBuilder("masterStep", jobRepository)
                .partitioner(slaveStep.getName(), partitioner)
                .step(slaveStep)
                .gridSize(2) // Number of partitions
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step slaveStep(ItemReader<RecurringEarning> reader,
                          RecurringEarningProcessor earningProcessor,
                          RecurringItemWriter recurringItemWriter) {
        return new StepBuilder("slaveStep", jobRepository)
                .<RecurringEarning, RecurringEarning>chunk(chunkSize, platformTransactionManager)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(earningProcessor)
                .writer(recurringItemWriter)
                .faultTolerant()
                .retryLimit(2)
                .retry(PessimisticEntityLockException.class)
                .build();
    }
```

What could have gone wrong here?

Comment: If gridSize = 1, then the `RecurringEarningPartitioner` should return a single partition with the entire dataset (ie min = 1 and max = 10254). Is that the case? Otherwise, this is a bug in the partitioner.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine i found the issue. It was an issue in RepositoryItemReader. It was not expecting as i wanted to, and i tried a Cursor implementation with a native SQL query. It worked fine as i expected. 
I will post the answer soon. Thank you for your time.